# Keeping floating menu items in line? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating the menu for a website right now and I'm running into a problem keeping the menu items from spilling over when the browser resizes.

To get an idea of what I'd like to do, this site does this: 
[Learn to Code](http://www.webdesigndegreecenter.org/learn-to-code/)

If you resize the window, for a while the menu items will keep moving over to the left until it gets to a point where the site responsively loads new content.

My site will not keep pushing the menu items to the left; rather the items spill over underneath like this:

[image]

[image]

Of course, here's the code:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <a href="index.php" id="home">
            <div id="logo">
                <img id="rumble-me" alt="logo" src="../assets/img/down-arrow-2-black-transparent-right.png" />
                <h1>My Logo</h1>
            </div>
        </a>

    <nav id="links">
        <a href="index.php">
            <div id="home-link" class="linkItem">
                <img alt="Home" src="../assets/img/home.png" />
                <h2>Home</h2>
            </div>              
        </a>

        <a href="members.php">
            <div id="members-link" class="linkItem">
                <img alt="Home" src="../assets/img/users.png" />
                <h2>Members</h2>
            </div>              
        </a>

        <!--etc.-->

    </nav>
</div>

#navigation {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-image: url('../assets/img/use_your_illusion-light.png');
position: fixed;
z-index: 1001;
}

#home {
float: left;   
}

#links {
height: 60px;
width: 39.5%;
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
}

#links > a {
float: left;  
display: block;
}

.linkItem {
height: 60px;
width: 80px;
display: inline-block;
}

#home-link {

}

#home-link > h2 {
margin-left: 13px;
}

#home-link > img {
margin-left: 25px;   
}
```

I only displayed what I think might be the most relevant HTML and CSS, if there are any questions comment away!

Comment: look into media queries

Comment: The code you gave [looks nothing like the picture](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/wY4Fw/). Please provide enough for us to recreate the issue

Comment: I didn't want to post more code for fear of posting too much. But I figure out my problem now luckily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it -> The individual link items should be floated right, the entire link section should be floated left, and given a **larger width**. Now it works!